# Dialogue System C#

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog

First thing first - I'm sorry for my poor English and I'm kinda new to this great community, so I'm really sorry if something is incorrect in my question.
In short - I've started with C# not so long ago (which means you find a lot of poor written code here) and now **I'm aiming to create a dialogue system**. Though I have some working sample, questions are:

- How to make everything not this lame and improve the code;
- Suggestions about improving performance;
- Overall advices (maybe there is some more suitable tools for doing this);

Right now I use **Finite-State Machine (FSM)** as a general concept, so that every state is a dialogue scene. The last one is made of NPC quote and set of Player responds.
By now everything is pretty basic. Here I have my class for Player responds.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Testing
{
    public class Player_Qoute : Label
    {
        public string Next_State { get; set; }//is used to tell, where to go next after choosing particular respond
    }
```

It's inherited from Label and has one additional field - next stage number, which is added in function below:

```
private void NPC_Quote(string path, string specification, RichTextBox info)
{
    StreamReader file = new StreamReader(path);//creating StremReader to read NPC quotes from .txt
    string line = "";//Creating string variable to read from
    try
    {
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)//readinf file line-by-line until the end
        {
            if (line.Contains(specification))//if line contains specified "tag"
            {
                line = line.Remove(0, specification.Length);//removing "tag" from line
                info.Text += line + "\n";//adding NPC line to the output field 
            }
        }
        file.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Problem reading file");
    }
}
```

This function parse through .txt file, searching for lines tagged "NPC_stage_n", where "n" - is a number of stage. This number is present at the end of every Player respond in .txt file and I put it in the "Next_Stage" field of Player_Quote objects.
The same idea is applied here, but now i dynamically create Player's responds (number of which varies from stage to stage). I'm facing some issues with appropriate placing of quotes on the GroupBox - sometimes they are missing a line or words, but I'm working on it:

```
void Quotes_Generation(string path, string specification, GroupBox parent)
{
    parent.Controls.Clear();//deleting previous Player qoutes
    int step = 0;//auxilary variable to separate quotes from each other by heigth
    StreamReader file = new StreamReader(path);//StreamReader to read Player responds from .txt
    string line = "";
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains(specification))
        {
            Player_Qoute quote = new Player_Qoute();//inherited from Label;
            quote.Name = "qoute_" + line.Remove(specification.Length, line.Length - specification.Length);
            quote.Location = new Point(10, 20 + step);
            quote.Size = new Size(360, 10);
            quote.Text = line.Remove(0, specification.Length);//deleting "search tag" from text
            quote.Text = quote.Text.Remove(quote.Text.Length-3, 3); //here we are deleting 3-digit number at the end of the string 
            //this number will show what is the next state of the dialogue if this Player respond is chosen.
            quote.Next_State = line.Remove(0,line.Length - 3);//storing 3-digit number in Player_Quote property
            using (Graphics g = CreateGraphics())//part of code which was borrowed from StackOverFlow and wasn't properly understood by me
            {
                SizeF size = g.MeasureString(quote.Text, quote.Font, 264);
                quote.Height = (int)Math.Ceiling(size.Height);
                quote.Text = quote.Text;
            }
            quote.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.Quote_Click);//creating event for choosing this respond
            parent.Controls.Add(quote);//adding respond to GroupBox
            step += (quote.Height+3);//increasing step
            if (parent.Height < step)//enlarging GroupBox
            {
                parent.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(parent.Width, step + 50);
                parent.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(parent.Width, step + 50);
            }
        }
    }
    file.Close();
}
```

And here is the Quote_Click event:

```
private void Quote_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Player_Qoute current = sender as Player_Qoute;//recognizing the sender
        richTextBox1.Text +=  Player_Name + "   -  " + current.Text + "\n";//adding Player respond with Player name to RichTextBox
        NPC_Quote(Application.StartupPath + "/Readme.txt", "NPC_stage_" + current.Next_State + ":", richTextBox1);//Adding new NPC line according to chosen respond
        Quotes_Generation(Application.StartupPath + "/Readme.txt", "Player_stage_" + current.Next_State + ":", groupBox1);//refreshing responds according to previous actions
    }
```

I'll appreciate all the advices!

Comment: If your code is working and you are looking for improvements and suggestions, you might get better results over at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).